# What is wrong with intellj?

Tags: intellij-idea

Why is the code in IntelliJ no longer fully readable (see screenshot)?
Is there a key combination or a setting option for this?

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That's something to do with your code folding settings. Docs here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html and here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding

Comment: STRG + Shift + numpad + is working, but only for the actual file.

Comment: Do you use any custom plugin (e.g. Advanced Java Folding)?

Comment: I have now deactivated the plugin and the code is displayed normally again. 
Thank you so much, you have saved my week.